# How to specify multiple included domains in SPF record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

Our business email is hosted on Google apps.  In addition, our web server may also send email.  Currently our SPF record in DNS looks like this:

```
domain.com.    IN   TXT    "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com -all"
```

This is all fine, however now we've outsourced our email list management to another company and we need to include a second domain with `include`.  So, I'm looking for something like:

```
domain.com.    IN   TXT    "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com include:otherdomain.com -all"
```

What is the correct syntax for this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

All SPF mechanisms, including `include`, can be used multiple times, separated by spaces:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:otherdomain.com -all"
```

Evaluation of `include` works this way:

- If the *included* data returned PASS, then the `include` itself generates a result (for example, `include:foo.bar` generates a PASS, but `-include:foo.bar` generates a FAIL).
- If the *included* data returned FAIL or NEUTRAL, then the `include` does not contribute to the result at all, and processing goes to your next mechanism.

See [SPF record syntax](http://www.openspf.net/SPF_Record_Syntax) and [RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208).

(Note that `redirect=` is not a mechanism but a global modifier, and cannot be repeated this way.)

Comment: found a cool simple site that did it for me.. http://spf.zone

Comment: The original cuestion includes an `a` after `v=spf1` but the answer doesn't. Is that a typo or does `a` mean something?

Comment: @Gonzalingui The `a` allows you to use your ip address to send mail for that specific domain.

Answer (score 9):

This is the correct syntax you requested

```
domain.com:    IN   TXT    "v=spf1  include:_spf.google.com include:otherdomain.com -all"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `include` mechanism to add each service in your SPF record:

```
v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com include:otherdomain.com -all
```

Make sure you don't create multiple SPF records on one domain. If you do, SPF will return PermError.

Also note that you don't exceed the [10 DNS lookup limit](https://dmarcly.com/blog/spf-permerror-too-many-dns-lookups-when-spf-record-exceeds-10-dns-lookup-limit) of SPF, otherwise SPF will return PermError too.

Answer (score 1):

`v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com include:seconddomain.com include:thirddomain.com -all` is the correct way